# React TS: Despite passing method through wrapper, child still can't access getPage()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to build a fetch method that can be shared to a bunch of Reader components through a higher order component. I believe I've built the HOC right, but I'm not 100% sure.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import base from "./firebase";
    export default (ChildComponent) => {
        class GetPage extends Component<{},any> {
            constructor(props: any) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                text: "Hii"
              };
            }

            public getPage(page: string) {
              base
                .fetch(page, { context: this, })
                .then(data => this.setState({ text: data }));
                console.log(this.state.text)
            }
            public render() {
                return <ChildComponent getPage={this.getPage} text={...this.state.text} {...this.props}/>;
            }
        }
        return GetPage;
    };
```

You can see that I'm importing the HOC on the second line , but despite this, the  'Reader' component is throwing an error that 'getPage' is no where to be found.

```
import * as React from "react";
import GetPage from "./fetch";

class Reader extends React.Component<{},any>{

    public componentWillMount() {
        this.getPage('1A1');
        }

    public render() {
    return <div{...getPage('1A1')}>{...this.state.text}</div>;
    }
}

export default (GetPage(Reader));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Reader component instead of accessing this.getpage try with this.props.getpage
and I don't understand why you are doing with following:

```
<div{...getPage('1A1')}>
```

Comment: The '...' before getPage is what TypeScript wanted to see.

Doing that did get rid of the error! But I got this instead. `Property 'getPage' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'`